# Visualizing 3D video sequence in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, graphics, 3d, voxel

I have a stack of 100 images of size 300 x 300 which represent a 3D volume. I have another 100 of these 3D volumes as a sequence. I have been trying to visualize this 3D image sequence data as a video where I can watch how the volume is changing over time and move around the scene to see the changes in the volume from different views.

I tried doing this in matplotlib but it only works on 3D point data and I could not figure out how to make it visualize a 3D stack of images as a video. I also did not see support for this in mayavi or plotly and I was wondering if there is a package that can do this visualization out of the box? I would like to see the video sequence As MIP and if possible to slice through them.

Comment: visualizing 3d volumes ("volumetric rendering") requires a bit of knowledge. and it strongly benefits from graphics acceleration. you should look for a course on computer graphics. or look for _programs_ for scientific visualization. you don't seem to _need_ to implement this. you just want visualization, right? then don't program this but find a program.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if ffmpeg will be any use to you- it lets you assemble videos from individual images: you might be able to use it to autogenerate videos from different viewing angles (or maybe even assemble a 'composite' video with different viewing angle sub-regions). Not the same as being able to move around the scene, but might give still give some insight.

Comment: You could take a look at [ParaView](https://www.paraview.org/). It is designed to visualize large high-dimensional datasets and also has a Python interface. The GUI is quite nice, but there is a bit of learning curve to it. So the [tutorial](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/Tutorials/index.html) might be good starting point.

Comment: I'm not sure if something like [pyqtgraph](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) would be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the [napari](https://napari.org/stable/) library python library.

---

You can install `napari` using `pip install napari`. [Here's](https://napari.org/stable/tutorials/fundamentals/installation.html#installation) the installation guide. 
 Note: You need to be on python 3.8 or greater.

I wrote a sample script with randomly generated noise as images:

```
import napari
import numpy as np

# Randonmly generated a images 
image_sequence = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(100, 300, 300), dtype=np.uint8)

viewer = napari.Viewer()
viewer.add_image(image_sequence)
viewer.layers[0].rendering = 'mip' # Maximum Intensity Projection (MIP)
viewer.dims.ndisplay = 3
napari.run()
```

###### Here's how it looks

[image]

To get the player click **Toggle ndisplay** button on the bottom left of the napari window or press **Ctrl+Y**.